# Erlang print processID?

Tags: io, erlang, pid

This is a really simple question pertaining to printing out the process id of a connection. For example printing out Listen in this one? I'm assuming Listen is a Pid btw...

```
{ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can print it with `io:format` using the `~p` format specifier, that can print any Erlang term:

```
> io:format("~p~n", [Listen]).
#Port<0.605>
```

(`Listen` is not actually a pid, but a port identifier.)

Comment: thanks btw is Socket in this a PiD?                                  {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen)